# Bootstrap (4.3.1) Card with Navigation Tabs - I need the "default" tab to be automatically selected

Tags: bootstrap-4, wai-aria

I have a Bootstrap Card and inside this card I have Navigation tabs that open tab-panes, I need to have the first (Default) Tab to be selected and opened when the user arrives on the page

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="profileTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="tabMain" data-toggle="tab"
                       href="#profileMain" role="tab"
                       aria-controls="profileMain" aria-selected="true">Main</a>
                </li>
.....
<div class="tab-content" id="profileTabsContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profileMain" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tabMain">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
```

I have tried `aria-expanded` `aria-selected` and `aria-pressed` in both the content and header but no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class `active` against the

- anchor with class `nav-link` i.e. `<a class="nav-link active" id="tabMain" data-toggle="tab" href="#profileMain" role="tab" aria-controls="profileMain" aria-selected="true">Main</a>`
- div with the class `tab-pane` i.e. `<div id="home" class="container tab-pane active">`

**working snippet**:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect - I missed it active both in the nav-link and tab-pane Thanks